# Clause where in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Table db1 AND db2

```
DB1
+-----------+------------+
|    id     |    nameDb  |
+-----------+------------+
|    1      |    name1   |
+-----------+------------+
|    2      |    name2   |
+-----------+------------+
|    3      |    name3   |
+-----------+------------+
```

DB2

```
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|    id      |   name     |   id_db1    |          date        |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|    1       |   test1    |      1      |  2013-05-10 10:00:00 |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|    2       |   test2    |      1      |  2013-05-10 11:00:00 |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|    3       |   test3    |      1      |  2013-05-10 11:10:00 |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|    4       |   test4    |      1      |  2013-05-10 11:40:00 |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

my query is this:

```
SELECT a.nameDb, b.name FROM db1 a 
LEFT JOIN db2 b ON b.id_db1 = a.id 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(b.name, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-05-10'
```

I need to return everything related to the day, which was not related must also appear...

Something Like

```
+------------+------------+
|    nameDb  |   name     |
+------------+------------+
|    name1   |   test1    |
+------------+------------+
|    name1   |   test2    |
+------------+------------+
|    name1   |   test3    |
+------------+------------+
|    name1   |   test4    |
+------------+------------+
|    name2   |   NULL     |
+------------+------------+
|    name3   |   NULL     |
+------------+------------+
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT a.nameDb, b.name FROM db1 a 
LEFT JOIN db2 b ON b.id_db1 = a.id 
and DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-05-10'
```

If you use columns from left outer joined tables in where clause it behaves like inner join

Comment: but consultation is being used

Comment: @IgorCiqueira, i didn't understand, what are you trying to say when you say "consultation is being used"

Comment: I'm sorry ... I am using is query but I can not view the data

Comment: @IgorCiqueira, it returns data check this [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c36e8/3), notice that your original query is using b.name and not b.date in DATE_FORMAT function

Comment: I actually checked, but in my query the left join is behaving like inner

Comment: @IgorCiqueira, where did appointment come from? can you create sql fiddle link with data and your actual query?

Answer (score 0):

You want an `outer join`. There's a good description of the different joins and their outputs here: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

You should just need a `RIGHT JOIN` or swap the tables around and you can use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT a.nameDb, b.name 
FROM db1 a 
  RIGHT JOIN db2 b ON b.id_db1 = a.id AND DATE_FORMAT(b.name, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-05-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the WHERE to an AND, to make the date check as part of your join condition:

```
SELECT a.nameDb, b.name FROM db1 a 
LEFT JOIN db2 b ON b.id_db1 = a.id 
AND DATE_FORMAT(b.name, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-05-10'
```